# Windows Phone CreateFolderAsync method is giving error when it awaits

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Am trying to learn about [WindowsPhone Files/Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) .
 While am writing the `CreateFolderAsync` method as per the msdn

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
 StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;    
 var dataFolder =await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
 //code goes here
}
```

### Giving an error

`Type  Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.StorageFolder> is not awaitable`

---

When i remove `await` keyword its just fine but am not getting `dataFolder.CreateFileAsync` method.
And am sure that i didn't miss any reference. Anybody can tell why this error happens?

Comment: It's because the method was not created as `Task` and thus is not awaitable. The answer @atomaras gave you is one of the correct solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting it to a Task before awaiting on it like so

```
await local.CreateFolderAsync(..).AsTask()
```